# The back button loads page as originally shown, without an indicator of new comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, live-refresh

After pressing "more comments", or "load comments", when the real time function returns, and then going to a new page, and then pressing back, the new comments aren't loaded. It's like they don't exist. A hard refresh is the only thing that seems to load them.

This type of bug breaks usability of the site for an end user, and I would like to request the developers support the back button. If they don't then I believe there should be some type of indicator letting the user know that their support of the back button doesn't exist.

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you're referring to, but I'm gonna guess you mean the real-time notification of new comments and *not* the indicator that shows up when there are simply more than 5 comments on a given post. If so, that's expected behavior: your browser caches the page as it was when you loaded it, not whatever happened while you had it open. If I'm wrong, edit to clarify please.

Answer (score 2):

That'll be because the comments are loaded in the DOM with javascript; and when you return to the page using your back button, your browser will load its cached version which hasn't got the DOM manipulations.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know _why_ it happens. It's actually quite obvious.

Comment: Right, so how is it a bug in SO then? Do you think it's a bug in your browser? There's not much SO can do about browser caching when it comes to back buttons.

Comment: loading the comments via ajax exclusively would fix this.

Comment: It would also result in a lot of useless calls to the server, and since this is most certainly an edge case, that seems unnecessary.